# Make HTML table from Associative Array

Tags: html, arrays, html-table, associative

I have sorted array that looks like this when var_dump.

```
array (size=11)

  'The Matrix' => float 9.5

  'Fight Club' => float 9.5

  'Inception' => float 8.5

  'The Usual Suspects' => float 7.5

  'Shutter Island' => float 7.5

  'The Prestige' => float 7

  'The Dark Knight' => float 7

  'The Departed' => float 6

  'Matchstick Men' => float 5.5

  'The Green Mile' => float 5

  'Forrest Gump' => float 4.5
```

Array is using titles and ratings of movies from database, so data in array will change, when movie or rating is added/changed in database. My question is:

How to make HTML table from this array?

Comment: Are you using PHP? What have you got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>
          <th>Movie</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          </tr>';
    foreach ($arr as $key=>$val) {
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$key.'</td>
                <td>'.$val.'</td>
              </tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```